# Inserting JSON data into D3 Bubble Chart Visualization

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to populate this graph (see URL below) with my own JSON data.
http://bl.ocks.org/phuonghuynh/54a2f97950feadb45b07

I'm new to JS and D3. I wrote some code in a file called parse.js that takes file.json and returns an array of objects, each object has an artist name and its frequency.

```
const data = require("./file.json");

Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
var size = Object.size(data);

var artists = [];

var Artfreq = function(artist, frequency)
{
    this.artist = artist;
    this.frequency = frequency;
};

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    var k = 0;
    if(artists.length == 0)
    {
        var newArtist = new Artfreq(data[i].artistName, 1);
        artists.push(newArtist);
    }
    else
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < artists.length; j++)
        {
            if(data[i].artistName == artists[j].artist)
            {
                artists[j].frequency += 1;
                k = 1;
            }
        }
        if(k != 1)
        {
            var newArtist = new Artfreq(data[i].artistName, 1);
            artists.push(newArtist);
        }
    }
}
console.log(artists);
```

I tested that the above code works as I expect with that console.log statement.

I downloaded the index.js and index.html code from the link above. I cannot figure out how to replace data.item with my artist array.

```
data: {
      items: [
        {text: "Java", count: "236"},
        {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
        {text: "Php", count: "170"},
        {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
        {text: "D", count: "12"},
        {text: "Python", count: "170"},
        {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
        {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
        {text: "Something", count: "170"},
      ],
      eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
      classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
    },
```

I have tried exporting/importing the artists array from the parse.js file that creates the artists array to the index.js file. I have tried copying and pasting (with minor mods) in the code from my parse.js file into the index.js file. I have run into several errors, including the cross-origin policy, syntax issues with export/import, etc. I have googled the individual errors, which have led me to do things like add type = "module" to the index.html file. Sadly, I end up in a loop where fixing one error causes another.

I know that eventually, I'll need to feed in the object data so that "text" maps to "artistName" and "count" matches to "frequency." However, I can't even get my data to import into that index.js file.

Would very much appreciate help. Thanks!

Comment: I'd look into reading the original JSON file using [`d3.json`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/tree/v1.2.0#json). You'd need to host the file somewhere on a webserver, but that is the most common d3 way of doing this

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll look into that.